# StringUtil cannot be resolved

Tags: java

Ругается на строки `result.append(StringUtil.reverse(str1 + "$"));` и `result.append(StringUtil.reverse(str2));`. При наведении отображается ошибка

> StringUtil cannot be resolved

Фрагмент кода:

```
package rts.util;

import org.jsoup.helper.StringUtil;

public class Crypto {

public static String getEncodedStringAlg1 (String str1, String str2) {
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
    result.append(StringUtil.reverse(str1 + "*"));
    result.append(StringUtil.reverse(str2));
    String str = getMd5(result.toString());
    return str.replaceAll("0", " ");        
}
```

Comment: Нужно как можно подробнее описать на что и как «ругается». В частности нужно указать: сообщение об ошибке, строку на которой возникает ошибка, если выброшено исключение то еще и трассировку стэка.

Comment: При наведение мышь к строку выходят сообщение: StringUtil cannot be resolved

Comment: Попробуйте собрать проект и скопируйте в вопрос (под вопросом кнопка «править») ошибки компиляции.  Укажите в вопросе как собирается проект, из какой библиотеки `StringUtil` и почему считаете что он должен работать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В [`StringUtil`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/helper/StringUtil.html) из jsoup нет метода `reverse`.

Скорее всего это попытка обратиться к [`StringUtils`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html) из Apache Commons.

Исправьте название класса и импорт:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;

...
StringUtils.reverse(str1 + "$")
```

Убедитесь, что подключена библиотека Apache Commons.

Comment: Спасибо! Вы мне помогли, и вправду я не добавил библиотеку Apache commons.

Comment: @Ulukmyrza Пожалуйста! Если проблема решена, [отметьте ответ как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) (слева от ответа должна быть серая галка, нажмите на нее).